# Set the left margin of paragraphs in a box enviroment

Tags: margins, indentation, boxes, framed

I'm now using `framed` package, and the output looks good for me. However, if I want all paragraph in this `framed` environment further indent for `2em`, I always manually use `\hangindent = 2em\hangafter = 0` at every beginning of a paragraph. But it is quite redundant. Even if I define a new command `\newcommand{\allindent}{\hangindent = 2em\hangafter = 0}`, it's still so inconvenient. How can I automatically indent the paragraphs in `framed`? (If there's no a box surrounding it, it is easy to do so.) By the way, the place of the sides of the `framed` is ideal for me, so I don't want to change it.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[margin=2cm, top=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,framed}
\parindent=0pt
\parskip=3pt
\OuterFrameSep = -4ex
\FrameSep = 7pt
\FrameRule = 1.3pt 

\begin{document}
\begin{framed}
\hangindent = 2em\hangafter = 0 These are some words. These are some words. These are some words. These are some words. These are some words. These are some words. These are some words.These are some words. These are some words. These are some words. These are some words. These are some words. These are some words.

\hangindent = 2em\hangafter = 0 These are some words. These are some words. These are some words. These are some words. These are some words. These are some words. These are some words.These are some words. These are some words. These are some words. These are some words. These are some words. These are some words. 

If I don't use the \verb"\hangindent" and \verb"\hangafter", the indentation is not I want.
\end{framed}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to `mdframed`.

A simple `innerleftmargin` declaration should do what you want.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[margin=2cm, top=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,mdframed}
\parindent=0pt
\parskip=3pt

\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}[innerleftmargin=2em,linewidth=1.3pt]
These are some words. These are some words. These are some words. These are some words. These are some words. These are some words. These are some words.These are some words. These are some words. These are some words. These are some words. These are some words. These are some words.

These are some words. These are some words. These are some words. These are some words. These are some words. These are some words. These are some words.These are some words. These are some words. These are some words. These are some words. These are some words. These are some words.

If I don't use the \verb"\hangindent" and \verb"\hangafter", the indentation is not I want.
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

---

### EDIT

To have top and bottom lines when the `mdframed` breaks a page use the option `everyline=true`.

Eventually act on the options `splitbottomskip` and `splittopskip` and set the options globally through `\mdfsetup`.

Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[margin=2cm, top=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,mdframed}
\mdfsetup{everyline=true,splittopskip=15pt,innerleftmargin=2em,linewidth=1.3pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\parindent=0pt
\parskip=3pt

\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}
These are some words. These are some words. These are some words. These are some words. These are some words. These are some words. These are some words.These are some words. These are some words. These are some words. These are some words. These are some words. These are some words.

These are some words. These are some words. These are some words. These are some words. These are some words. These are some words. These are some words.These are some words. These are some words. These are some words. These are some words. These are some words. These are some words.

If I don't use the \verb"\hangindent" and \verb"\hangafter", the indentation is not I want.
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It looks good. Another question: if I want `mdframed` "enclose" the box by the bottom (and top) line in every page when the box is too height so that crossing pages occurs, how can I do?

Comment: @Eric See the edit.

Comment: @Eric Happy to help!